# django-1.4.3 how to add categories?how posts when click on the category?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to add categories to my blog, I have model class like below. Please tell me if anything is wrong. How can I display posts when user clicks on the categories. Thank you in advance.

**Models.py**

```
class Posts(models.Model):   
    category=models.ForeignKey('indianapp.Category')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_post_detail', (),{'slug':self.slug,})

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug=sluggify(self.title)
        super(Posts,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_by_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

**Views.py**

```
def view_category(request,slug):
   catego=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=slug)
   category=Category.objects.all()
   posts = Posts.objects.all()
   category_posts = []
   for post in posts:
     if post.category.filter(Posts,slug=slug):
        category_posts.append(post)
   category = Category.objects.filter(slug=slug)
   pagedata.update({'post_list': category_posts})
   return render_to_response('listpage.html',pagedata)
```

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)','indianapp.views.view_category',name='view_by_category'),
```

**View_category.html**

```
{% block title %}{{ category.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if post_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in post_list %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>There are no posts.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

`category_posts = category.posts_set.all()`

or

`category_posts = Posts.objects.filter(category=category)`

I encourage you to read Django tutorial.